# Set a variable to a value inside asynchronous function

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable, subscribe

First of all i know than it can't be done like that because you can't initialize variables inside asynchronous functions.

But i need you guys to make this correct for me.

in this example i have an observable and i want to return it's variable and use it in other functions

```
    id:string;
    constructor(){
      this.user$.subscribe(data=>{
      this.id = data.uid})
      console.log(this.id) //undefined
}
```

> I know this is wrong but i don't know the correct way to do it.

for example i need the id of the user here! but since it's undefined i get error

```
 getCat() :Observable<boolean>{
      return this.afs.collection('users').doc(this.id).collection('categories').get().pipe(
        map(data => {
          if(data.size > 0){
            return true
          }else{
            return false
          }
        })
      )
  }
```

Comment: can you share the sample JSON

Comment: the sample JSON of what?

Comment: can I see the data?

Comment: Well, you're not returning the data, but `true` or `false`. Return the data instead and you will be able to access it's variables.

Comment: (if you know) the data is exactly the facebook's user object because i used facebook to login to the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call for getCat function should be called in the subscribe of the user observable I mean after the user id is get it.

```
this.user$.subscribe(data=>{

      this.id = data ? data.uid : null;
      console.log(this.id); //should have a value
      this.getCat() // just call the function here 
});
```

Comment: it's undefined because you can not initialize variables inside async functions but i'm looking for the solution

Comment: actually is undefined because you response comes undefined  try by logging console.log(data)

Comment: logging that do nothing for me i need the value to use it in other methods :(

Comment: pff, Im suggest you  to log because this.id is null because data is null or data.uid is null. let me modify my example.

Comment: if i log data it's not null but this.id is always undefined

Comment: Ready take a look at the modification. 
if you need the user id property you need to wait until the user response. and it is going tobe inside of the subscribe.